# an almost failed space invaders project in godot

Tags: gdscript

[image]
thats the line Im getting the error on and those line mainly just go away. this is gdscript in godot

Comment: Please edit your question and copy-paste the code and the error instead of using screenshots. Other folks will have an easier time finding their error and the solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

GDscript uses a syntax similar to Python, where *indention* is important. You can learn more about the basics of GDScript [here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html).

In your code, the parser expects that `func` be stuck completely on the left, with no whitespace before the keyword.

That would probably fix an issue; your still stuck with having 3 times the same function with the same signature, and I don't think the parser will like that (especially if one of them has no body). Looking at your code, you should probably keep only the first one and delete the other two.

Comment: thank you but I was able to fix this I just deleted the process delta lines and it worked

Comment: but thank you for taking your time to help me

Comment: @NoahAnaya You can post what you've described as an answer and accept it, it will help people with the same problem finding an answer more easily.